# UITextView height not resizing in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uitextview

Following are the constraints on `UITextView` :

[image]

**Constraints of other subviews :**

**UILabel :**

[image]

**UIView :**

[image]

**Scrolling is disabled :**

[image]

**viewDidLoad :**

```
self.tableLeadsOverview.estimatedRowHeight = 100
self.tableLeadsOverview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

**Content :**

> 1527 Clover Ridge Dr Burlington VA USA 90210

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Don't you need to call `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` on a `tableView` for any resizing to occur? You can try it in `textViewDidChange`

Comment: @RakeshaShastri : Why would I need that in auto layout ?

Comment: Because tableView needs to be updated? You already have a set height for tableViewCell. If a tableView needs a layoutChange you need to call those 2 methods after making the necessary changes, which your autolayout code will do for you. You just need to call those methods for them to reflect.

Comment: are you getting any constraint conflicts in the console output?

Comment: Please share all the constraints. I mean, you should check for the constraints on UILabel too.

Comment: @lindanordstrom : No conflicts.

Comment: @BhavinKansagara : There you go. Updated the question.

Comment: Did you check with `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` ?

Comment: The UILabel has a height of 39.5 set, what height do you end up with currently, and what is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: set this translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints of textview to false textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: @RakeshaShastri : Again, beginUpdates, endUpdates are not required here. Constraints will take care of that. Just need to check what's wrong with my constraints.

Comment: Set height constraint to UITextview and give relation greater than or equal

Comment: @lindanordstrom : I am getting the same height for UILabel as it is set. UITextView's height is what I am concerned about. It is coming out to be equal to UILabel.

Comment: @ShauketSheikh : I am not setting constraints programmatically.

Comment: @karthikeyan : Yup, already tried that.

Comment: let me try in my side sample code.

Comment: try removing bottom constraint to UILable

Comment: Oh yes, I misunderstood your question. I see now. I had the same issue once, try to do `layoutIfNeeded()` on the textView once the text has been set. And also, maybe you'll need to look into `systemLayoutSizeFitting` for the base view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the UILabel's bottom constraint. Try removing it, as you are giving the height constraint to the label so, it will always remains on the top left corner OR if you want to keep the label at the centre of the cell.

Try and share the results.

Comment: That's it. That was the issue.

Comment: @karthikeyan : Thanks a lot. Actually read this answer's notification before your comment's notification.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-resizing will not work in this case, because `UITextView` contains scrollview to display its contains and scrollview having its `contentSize` and `frame`, So if its content/text increase it increases its `contentSize` not the frame, so the cell size will not increases automatically. Follow the below steps to solve this.

1. With the existing constraints set a height constraint for the
   `UITextView` and take an outlet of it to the cell class.
2. Take the reference outlet of the UITextView to the cell class also
3. Now come to the `CellForRowAtIndexPath` data-source method of
   `UITableView` here first you set the text/content to the
   `UITextView` and after that set the `UITextView's` height constraint
   as `UITextView's` `contentSize.height` using the height constraint
   outlet you took above.

Any doubt let me know.

Comment: Good point. Tried the same but the constraint's constant is coming as 35.5 which is incorrect.

Comment: you have to set the height constraint = UITextViewOutlet.contentSize.height

Comment: Yup. Did that only

Comment: remove height constraint for the label

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on a similar cell like yours.

My solution is to create an label with flexible height to show the content of the textField. The label has all the constraints as the textField, except the height constraint, with `numberOfLines` set to `0` so that it can help you resize the `rowHeight`. When not editing, hide the textField. When the user selected the row (to start editing), hide the label, show the textField, and call `[textField becomeFirstResponder]`.

A little tricky. :]